# How to make CSS Vars work in all browsers

Tags: css, variables, browser

I am using a simple scheme of css vars for colors:
Definition:

```
:root {
    --color0: #ffffff;  
    --color1: #000000;  
}
```

and reference

.className { color:var(--color0); }

in some browsers it worked immediately, in other you needed to reset cache and then colors showed.

I forced to load from server, not from cache, with metatags but didn't work. I know it's not recommended to load from server permanently, and it's not good idea, ask everyone to reset their browsers cache.

How can I get css vars work properly for all browsers ?

Comment: var() doesn't work in all browsers, but classes do. Make a class as such as .red{color:#ff0000;} and add it to an element.

Comment: vars work on the vast majority of popular browsers now. It sounds like your problem is one of getting cached cleared - what has made you think it is to do with vars though?